# Use of UUIDs (Primary key) in a REST API

Tags: database, rest, database-design, relational-database

I faced the problem bellow when I designed our new app. 
We are thinking to have one extra column for some tables which is a UUID for security purposes. 
So, there are two different solutions. 
First is to have an extra column (UUID) on top of primary key which is a serial. In that case you need some more calls just to get the primary key from UUID.
Second is to have a UUID as a primary key and expose this ID to the REST level. I am not sure that is a good practice to do that.

What do you think? What is the preferred solution for you?

Comment: For security, you might consider using a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) instead of UUID.  Having both UUID and primary key doesn't make sense to me unless such primary key is a natural key and it then treated like an ordinary column instead of an id.

Comment: For security you should take a look at security.SE : for instance https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177171/security-tokens-for-external-exposure-uuid-or-hmac-jwt-hash. For the ID/UUID stuff, at worst you'll need to manage an ID/UUID cache.